# scala list counting element and find indices from other list

Tags: scala

Does anybody have a nice idea for a nice implementation of this:

```
//Input
val sequenceRef = List("a","b","c","d")        //no doublon
val listToCount = List("b", "c", "b", "a")    //possible doublon

//Output
val listOutput = List(1, 2, 1, 0)
```

1 --> there is one "a" in listToCount and it is at the first indice in listRef 
2 --> there is two b" in listToCount and it is at the second indice in listRef 
3 --> there is one "c" in listToCount and it is at the third indice in listRef 
0 --> there is no d in listToCount

Comment: For next time, please post the data in a copy/pastable format.

Answer (score 3):

```
val result = sequenceRef.map(x => listToCount.count(_ == x))
println(result)
```

will give you:

```
List(1, 2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way that uses an intermediary `Map` to avoid having to go through `listToCount` for every element of `sequenceRef`, at the cost of having to keep another collection in memory:

```
scala> val sequenceRef = List("a","b","c","d")
sequenceRef: List[String] = List(a, b, c, d)

scala> val listToCount = List("b", "c", "b", "a")
listToCount: List[String] = List(b, c, b, a)

scala> val keysCount = listToCount.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
keysCount: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 1)

scala> sequenceRef.map(keysCount.getOrElse(_, 0))
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 1, 0)
```